How to display missing commands in the command palette?
In VS Code 1.92.1 on macOS and Ubuntu, searching for Jupyter All returns 5 results in the keyboard shortcuts, but no results in the command palette.
Is it possible to make them appear there too?
There’s a screenshot of the problem here:
https://i.sstatic.net/3PF1zhlD.png
Stackoverflow doesn’t accept images if the post is too short, so that’s why I’m only posting the link.
